# DNS Forward Lookup is Failing in Linux

Tags: bind, reverse-dns, oracle-rac

I am installing a two node RAC on my testbed (virtualbox), i have setup the DNS server, forward lookup is not working but reverse lookup is, PFB

```
[root@dbwr1 log]# nslookup dbwr1.localdomain
Server:     192.168.24.1
Address:    192.168.24.1#53

** server can't find dbwr1.localdomain: NXDOMAIN

[root@dbwr1 log]# nslookup 192.168.24.41
41.24.168.192.in-addr.arpa  name = dbwr-scan.localdomain.

[root@dbwr1 log]#
[root@dbwr1 log]# nslookup 192.168.24.42
42.24.168.192.in-addr.arpa  name = dbwr-scan.localdomain.

[root@dbwr1 log]# nslookup 192.168.24.43
43.24.168.192.in-addr.arpa  name = dbwr-scan.localdomain.
```

**Scan IP List**

```
192.168.24.41 dbwr-scan.localdomain dbwr-scan
192.168.24.42 dbwr-scan.localdomain dbwr-scan
192.168.24.43 dbwr-scan.localdomain dbwr-scan
```

**forward.zone**

```
[root@dbwr1 log]# cat /var/named/localdomain.zone
N SOA dbwr1.localdomain.com. root.localdomain.com. (
2014051001 ; serial
3600 ; refresh
1800 ; retry
604800 ; expire
86400 ; minimum
)
@ IN NS dbwr1.localdomain.
localhost IN A 127.0.0.1
dbwr1 IN A 192.168.24.1
dbwr2 IN A 192.168.24.2
dbwr1-priv IN A 192.168.10.1
dbwr2-priv IN A 192.168.10.1
dbwr1-vip IN A 192.168.24.31
dbwr2-vip IN A 192.168.24.32
dbwr-scan IN A 192.168.24.41
dbwr-scan IN A 192.168.24.42
dbwr-scan IN A 192.168.24.43
```

**content of named.conf**

```
[root@dbwr1 log]# cat /etc/named.conf
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//
// See the BIND Administrator's Reference Manual (ARM) for details about the
// configuration located in /usr/share/doc/bind-{version}/Bv9ARM.html

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.24.1;};
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
    secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
    allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.24.1;};

    /*
     - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
     - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
       recursion.
     - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
       control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
       cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
       attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
       reduce such attack surface
    */
    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};


zone "localdomain.com" IN {
type master;
file "localdomain.zone";
allow-update { none; };
};

zone "24.168.192.in-addr.arpa." IN {
type master;
file "24.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
allow-update { none; };
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

**IP configuration**

```
[root@dbwr1 log]# ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.24.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.24.255
        inet6 fe80::2e2:d129:475:e4ec  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:8b:c7:b1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32  bytes 4389 (4.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
        inet6 fe80::29a6:749e:ebc2:9160  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:18:8c:83  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 33  bytes 4426 (4.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.8  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::72e5:e509:b983:7879  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:0b:4d:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3113  bytes 289859 (283.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1868  bytes 307668 (300.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 262  bytes 21283 (20.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 262  bytes 21283 (20.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:6c:b4:75  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Refers to the config you attached Your local root domain is : localdomain.com

If you want lookup hostname dbwr1.localdomain then the right command is :

```
$ nslookup dbwr1.localdomain.com
```

A slight correction to the NS record, It seems necessary like this:

```
@ IN NS dbwr1.localdomain.com.
```

The resulting output should be this IP `192.168.24.1` refers to A record :

```
dbwr1 IN A 192.168.24.1
```

Hope this will help